# Android run shell script via makefile for every platform mentioned in APP_ABI

Tags: makefile, java-native-interface, ndk-build, android.mk

I have a Android native application which builds for platform x86, armeabi and armeabi-v7a. Now depending upon whether the platform is x86 or arm, I need to run the script accordingly with the corresponding arguments so appropriate third party tool environment variables are set. I tried doing below:

```
.o.cpp:
      ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
            $(info $(shell ($(CACHE_LOCAL_PATH_MAIN)/setup_tool.sh x86)))
      else
            $(info $(shell ($(CACHE_LOCAL_PATH_MAIN)/setup_tool.sh arm)))
      endif
```

But the problem is, when the makefile is parsed, these scripts get run in the initial phase itself 3 times and not before compilation of every platform begins. Is there a way to get this fixed so the script gets run just before the compilation for every platform begins? Thanks.

**UPDATED with Android.mk file**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \ <path_to_include_files> 

LOCAL_CFLAGS := <cflags included here> 

LOCAL_LDLIBS := <ld libs included here> 

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <src files to be compiled> 

LOCAL_MODULE := <module_name> 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := <shared libs on which we are dependent> 

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := <static libs> 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: If you have **Android.mk**, then the best practice is to put all relevant make statements there. Remember that **Android.mk** is in the end just a makefile, and follows the same syntax rules and lifecycle as a usual makefile, only it is included from the sophisticated framework of NDK, and used multiple times (once per ABI), and sets the native library as target. So you can run the `setup_tool.sh` as a dependency of the native library.

Comment: Yes, we are using Android.mk. Can you please care to share how I add shell script as a dependency for the shared object that I am targeting? The format for building the .so looks like the one I added into my question.

Comment: When do you intend to use these environmental variables? In the execution of that rule, or in some other rule?

Comment: These environment variables shall be used by the third party tools to appropriately inject part of the code depending upon whether it is x86 or arm build that is currently going on, and since we simply use `ndk-build` and all the makefiles for different platforms gets parsed in the beginning itself, I am finding it hard to ensure this script gets run just before the compilation of this shared library for the specific platform begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, but not elegant solution is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) 
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \ <path_to_include_files> 

LOCAL_CFLAGS := <cflags included here> 

LOCAL_LDLIBS := <ld libs included here> 

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /tmp/dummy.x86.c
else
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /tmp/dummy.arm.c
        $(info $(shell ($(CACHE_LOCAL_PATH_MAIN)/setup_tool.sh arm)))
endif

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += <src files to be compiled> 

LOCAL_MODULE := <module_name> 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := <shared libs on which we are dependent> 

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := <static libs> 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

.PHONY: /tmp/dummy.x86.c /tmp/dummy.arm.c

/tmp/dummy.x86.c:
        $(CACHE_LOCAL_PATH_MAIN)/setup_tool.sh x86
        @touch $@

/tmp/dummy.arm.c:
        $(CACHE_LOCAL_PATH_MAIN)/setup_tool.sh arm
        @touch $@
```

One caveat: this will link the library every time, even if nothing changed. You can set dependencies carefully instead of `.PHONY` to improve this.

Comment: Bravo!!, it does seem to run the script once for the arm build and once for the x86 build(which should be good enough). I can probably add the new files that gets generated to `.gitignore`. I am trying to figure out a different issue after these changes. Once the shell script is run and environment variables are set even after `sourcing` the shell script, those variables have not been set into the main shell script from which I triggered compilation, due to which the third party tool is unable to run since `PATH` has not got updated and which is what I am currently investigating.

Comment: to avoid issues with GIT, you can put the file outside your version controlled directories, and use the absolute path to these files everywhere.

Comment: You are right, **make** opens a secondary shell which does not propagate to the shell that is used to compile. The above hack is useful if the script copies CPU-dependent files from place to place, or makes other global changes. If your `setup_tool.sh` prepares CFLAGS etc, you need a different techinque.

Comment: I ended up writing a script that first sets up environment for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` and then run `ndk-build` with `APP_ABI:="armeabi armeabi-v7a"`, copied the shared objects from libs folder to temp folder, then ran similar steps for x86 again and copied back the libs of armeabi and armeabi-v7a back to the original libs folder. The reason I had to do a copy was everytime ndk-build is run, it deletes everything in the libs folder and running ndk-build for x86 was resulting in libs for armeabi and v7a to be deleted as well.

Comment: I would rather use `ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi armeabi-v7a" NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT=libs/arm` followed by `ndk-build APP_ABI="x86" NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT=libs/x86`